# How can I change an object type in JSON string?

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I need to parse JSON string using java and change an object type of a field. For example, I have JSON string below:

```
{
   "_id" : "54c955492b7c8eb21818bd09"
   "firstName": "my name"
}
```

I would like my JSON string to be like this:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("54c955492b7c8eb21818bd09")
   "firstName": "my name"
}
```

How can I achieve this? I am using Gson parser.

Comment: Syntax errors aside, the second isn't JSON. The way I've seen MongoDB OIDs encoded is `"_id": { "$oid": "54c955492b7c8eb21818bd09" }`.

Comment: Yes. How can I change id type of first JSON so that Gson can deserialize it to my User object that contains ObjectId field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using regex:

```
jsonString.replaceAll("(\"_id\" : )(\"[^\"]*\")", "$1ObjectId($2)");
```

Answer (score -1):

changing a json object to an actual json string is done like this:

```
JsonParser p = new JsonParser();

JsonElement r = p.parse("{
   \"_id\" : \"54c955492b7c8eb21818bd09\"
   \"firstName\": \"my name\"
}");
JsonObject ob = r.getAsJsonObject();

r.toString();
```